# External video cards with MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I need to connect two displays to my MacBook Pro, and I [read](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/M9321G/B?pqid=QTPAYYDKUAXX4J9A2AU29UFHH24YYXXXF) a recommendation to use external video cards to accomplish this. How can I do this? Do I just buy a video card and some kind of case which can connect to Thunderbolt? I'd really like to use Thunderbolt as it's so much faster than USB2.0.

Since I'm getting a 17" MacBook Pro, I'm also getting an expresscard port. Will I be able to do something with this? Cheap is the price I'm looking for. :)

Comment: Did you ever get an external graphics card? I had a few questions... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75427/thunderbolt-graphics-cards

Comment: Yes, I got the Matrox TripleHeadToGo over DisplayPort. It works great for Windows and OSX, but not for Linux. It simply displays my two 1920x1080 displays as one 3840x1080 display so window movement and alignment doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The most supported option would be to get a pair of Thunderbolt displays and use those. Note that will black out the screen on your MacBook ([source](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4885)).

I don't think there are good cheap options out there.

Answer (score 0):

These EVGA boxes will do the trick, just don't expect them to have full hardware acceleration, but they work for displaying data and most programs fine. $60

http://amzn.com/B003L53C2E

But Matrox makes a non-cheap version called the Triple-head-to-go $300+